# Labeling for two systems of two equations

Tags: equations, align

[image]

I've tried eqnarray, align, equation with array, etc... but I can't figure out to make them like the picture...please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you've tried so far (MWE, minimal compilable code example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\begin{split}
a+b & =c+d+e   \\
c   & =f+g
\end{split}         \\
\begin{split}
a+b+c & = d+e+f   \\
g   & =h+i+j+k
\end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I missed \\ in between the splits! Thank you so much!